# How to build syntactic tree with line crossing from one phrase to another

Tags: linguistics, qtree

I need to build a line from VP to PP but the order does not allow me this.
I have:

```
\Tree [.S [.VP [\qroof{\textit{dūka dīd-a}}.NP ] [.V \textit{mšūy-ā-} ] ] [.NP [.ProN \textit{-la} ] ] [.VP [.V' ] [.PP [.P \textit{xazır} ] [\qroof{\textit{šwīs-e}}.NP ] ] ] ]
```

Which gives me something like this (made it in another app):
[image]

I want something like the line in the example (a), where the line from the second VP goes to N:[image]

Answer (score 1):

Discontinuous constituents are not permissible trees, which is why none of the standard tree drawing tools will allow you to do this. But you can fake it easily with the TikZ tree packages, either `tikz-qtree` (which has the same basic syntax as `qtree`) or `forest` (which is much more powerful.)  Here's a solution using both. I would recommend `forest` going forward.

(Linguistics related comment: I've removed lines between terminal node labels and words, since this is syntactically incorrect.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree,tikz-qtree-compat}
\begin{document}

\texttt{forest} solution
\begin{forest}
[S 
    [VP,name=VP [NP [\textit{dūka dīd-a},roof]] [V\\\textit{mšūy-ā-} ] ] 
    [NP [ProN\\\textit{-la} ] ] 
    [VP [V ] [PP,name=PP [P\\\textit{xazır}]  [NP [ \textit{šwīs-e},roof ]]]]
]
\draw (VP.south) -- (PP.south);
\end{forest}

\texttt{tikz-qtree} solution
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\Tree [.S 
      [.\node(VP) {VP}; [.NP \edge[roof]; {\textit{dūka dīd-a}} ] [.V\\\textit{mšūy-ā-} ] ] 
      [.NP [.ProN\\\textit{-la} ] ] 
      [.VP [.V ] [.\node (PP){PP}; [.P\\\textit{xazır} ] [.NP \edge[roof]; {\textit{šwīs-e}} ]  ] ] ]
\draw (VP.south) -- (PP.south);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]